# Java process problem in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, process

This is my code:

```
final String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C pelda.exe";
final Process tool_proc = null;

Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            tool_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run_tool);
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};    

Thread th = new Thread(doRun);
th.start();

InputStream toolstr = tool_proc.getInputStream();
```

After the eclipse gives this warning message fot the tool_proc variable:

> The final local variable tool_proc
>   cannot be assigned, since it is
>   defined in an enclosing type

I dont't know why my code doesn't work

please help me

Comment: Please, use formatting for code and compiler messages.

Comment: Look out for a `NullPointerException` on that final line! The asynchronous thread will not have set `tool_proc` on time.

Answer (score 6):

The `final` modifier forbids changing the variable once it has been set. Kevin gives an excellent explanation of why you can't use it in this context.

The construction you have chosen for requires you to introduce a field in the parent class and set it via `run()`:

```
class MyClass {
    Process tool_proc = null;

    void myFunction() {
        final String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C pelda.exe";
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tool_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run_tool);
                    } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread th = new Thread(doRun);
        th.start();

        // tool_proc will be null at this point!
        InputStream toolstr = tool_proc.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

In the above code I have demonstrated that `tool_proc` will always be `null` on the last line, as the thread has in all liklihood not finished its execution by this time!

You can expect `NullPointerException`s!

---

It seems what you are trying to do is very similar to [this article about capturing application output asynchronously](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4). It's a good read, and explains why conventional approaches can cause problems. I have an implementation very similar to their `StreamGobbler` (article page 4).

Comment: You can add tool_proc.waitfor() before the getInputStream() line to fix the NullPointerException.

Comment: That will not work either, as the variable hasn't been instantiated yet. You can't call a function on an empty pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I know a good trick since i'm C++ coder and always want pointers in java :

```
final String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C pelda.exe";
final Process tool_proc[] = new Process[1];

Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            tool_proc[0] = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run_tool);
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};    

Thread th = new Thread(doRun);
th.start();

InputStream toolstr = tool_proc.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tool_proc` variable is `final` - final variables can only be assigned once, and you already assigned it the value `null` in the declaration.  Removing the `null` assignment won't work because the runnable can be called more than once, resulting in multiple assignment.  <strike>So your best option is to remove the `final` keyword and it should compile, at least</strike>

### Edit

As noted in my comment to my answer, I neglected to account for the fact that `tool_proc` is a local variable, and without the `final` modifier it cannot be accessed from the anonymous `Runnable` subclass.  As Paul first noted in his answer, you'll have to use a non-final field to store the `Process` object.

Comment: Just now noticed you're dealing with a local variable, so you can't just remove the `final` keyword.  See Paul's solution, he explains it there.

Answer (score -2):

Initial value of final field cannot be changed. Remove final modificator from tool_proc:

```
Process tool_proc = null;
```

Comment: This will not work either, because the variable is not defined within the scope of the defined class `Runnable`. You could define a private field in the parent class.